# install canon printer Pixma G2000 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

I had followed the steps how to install canon printer Pixma G2000 from this blog. However, I get the errors as follow upon running command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev
Reading package lists… Done
Picking ‘cups’ as source package instead of ‘cups-common’
Picking ‘gutenprint’ as source package instead of ‘gimp-gutenprint’
E: Unable to find a source package for gimp-gutenprint
```

The blog web address as follow:
https://blog.droidzone.in/…/how-to-install-printers-for-ca…/
Does anybody know how to fix this one?
Currently, I'm using turboprint but in trial mode. After 30 days, turboprint for linux will expire. Hope to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: here a solution
https://askubuntu.com/questions/873640/how-to-solve-canon-pixma-g2000-driver-problems-on-ubuntu-16-04/943899#943899

Comment: here a solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/873640/how-to-solve-canon-pixma-g2000-driver-problems-on-ubuntu-16-04/943899#943899 I added some details for your issue

Comment: here a solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/873640/how-to-solve-canon-pixma-g2000-driver-problems-on-ubuntu-16-04/943899#943899 I added some details for your issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. Still a newbie. But I got my canon Pixma mg3051 to work by using USB and installing the Pixma 2900 driver and by changing its name to 3051. Plug the printer in via USB and add printer. If your printer is not on the list like mine I went for the model closest to mine then when the details came on screen just changed name. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the blog post you referred to.
I believe your problem is because you may not have added the apt sources as advised on the first step.

These are the lines you need to add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Alternately, you may create a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Do an `sudo apt update`, and now continue with the steps as mentioned on the [blog post](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

I got my Pixma 3051 just to work today after alot of Hassel. I plug it in via USB. In the dash select printer, add printer, select the make then it will search for a driver. If it doesn't find one select your driver from the listed. If it's not there select the one closest to it. It will show your printers details now change them to your printer name and run a test page.
The closest printer to mine was the Canon Pixma MG2900.

Comment: How about Canon Pixma G2000? I think there is no closer printer for it right?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first contribution to the community. I finally found a solution to install cannon g2000 driver on Ubuntu 16.04. The preinstalled version of gutenprint on Ubuntu 16.04 is 5.2.11 .. we have to update gutenprint to 5.2.13 this version has the g2000 driver.

Follow the steps below:

1. Type `sudo -H nautilus` in the terminal  file explorer with root access will open now go to sources.list and add the source links in sept 2.
2. These are the lines you need to add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
   deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install libgutenprint-dev build-essential`
5. `sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev`
6. `sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev`
7. `wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/gutenprint-5.2.13.tar.bz2/download`
8. `tar xvf download`
9. `cd gutenprint-5.2.13`
10. `./configure`
11. `make`
12. `sudo make install`

Now go to `usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/printers.xml`

If you find cannon pixima g2000 series in this printer list your driver has been installed successfully. (Use control + f and search for g2000)