# Canon Pixma G1400 no drivers on Ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: printing, canon, ubuntu-mate, ubuntu-drivers

I cant install the printer Canon Pixma G1400 there are no drivers.

I found this.
[how to solve Canon Pixma G2000 driver problems on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873640/how-to-solve-canon-pixma-g2000-driver-problems-on-ubuntu-16-04%C2%A0)

it looks complicated...something more simple;

Comment: I see Canon supply a linux driver for the G3000 and the G4000; we can only suggest you look at turboprint http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Canon_PIXMA_G1000series

Comment: something free i would apreciate it